# Laptop reboot when I want to shut down

Tags: 13.04, shutdown, thinkpad, reboot

I'm using a Lenovo Thinkpad Edge e130 with Ubuntu 13.04.
I don't know why, but when I try to shut down my laptop, it happens really often that the computer restarts. Does someone has the same issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it with `sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools`.

Hope it helps.